# Pre-update and post-update in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, rdbms

I want to use preupdate and postupdate concepts in my application.

The purpose is i want to get all values of a particulra record which is being updated and insert these values as  a record  along with new values in a table named audit.

Can any one give some suggestions or pointers on this.

Thanks,
Narendra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**0** You can use [HibernateInterceptors](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/events.html)

**1** You can do it programatically at service layer

**2** You can either implement this things by database [`TRIGGERS`](http://databases.about.com/od/administration/a/triggers.htm) then your DB will handle this.

Comment: imho triggers is a bad choice as hibernate won't be aware of resulting modifications, you will have to manually refreh the related entity in hibernate session which is a performance issue

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 ways to achieve this:

1. Hibernate Interceptors.  See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/events.html
2. Database level triggers/stored procedures.

You use the first if the pre/post functionality is business logic related -- i.e. your application is going to act on the update.

You use the second if you are only doing data level changes and the application doesn't need to know about it.

Comment: I am trying to get current data in database by using org.hibernate.event.PreUpdateEvent.getOldState(). but it returning null. If i use org.hibernate.event.PreUpdateEvent.getState() then I am getting new values(which are new value inserted into db). How can i get current record from db before updating.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look to Hibernate Envers. It does the Audit for you.

http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/index.html